# Using factory with nested relationships in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, eloquent, factory, laravel-8

My models are `User`, `Post` and `Category`.

I'm trying to use factories to seed all the data.
The first level (Users with posts) work fine by doing

```
// Create random users
User::factory()
    ->times(10)
    ->hasPosts(10)
    ->hasCategories(1)
    ->create();
```

But I want each post to have a category.
I've tried to do this (based on [this article](https://stefanzweifel.io/posts/2020/09/17/nested-states-in-laravel-8-database-factories/)):

```
User::factory()
    ->times(10)
    ->has(
        PostFactory::times(5)
            ->hasCategories(1)
            ->create()
    )
    ->hasCategories(1)
    ->create();
```

But throws this error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `posts` (`description`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (odio facilis molestiae, 2020-11-29 21:22:50, 2020-11-29 21:22:50))
```

### UPDATE: ADDED SIMPLIFIED MIGRATIONS

Posts and categories are linked thought a `many to many`

#### Users migration

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        ...
    });
}
```

#### Posts migration

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->text('title');
        $table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('user_id')
            ->references('id')->on('users')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

#### Categories migration

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May I see your posts migration!Add it in your question...

Comment: I've added the migrations :D